# arduino + gprs/gsm shield

Tags: asp.net, arduino, gsm, gprs

I am currently working on an arduino project as well as an asp.net web application.
my arduino project is using several sensors whose values/readings I need to display on my web application. I also have a gsm/gprs shield which I am hoping will achieve the sending of sensor values.

my problem is I don't know how to achieve this. there is a post which mentions about web service. do I also need to write it.
I need guidance,how do I achieve my objective.
thank you

Comment: This question is very broad. Show us what you have already. The Arduino has its own subforum at stackoverflow.... creating an HTTP host is rather easy in it. And the asp just need its "page source" in the Arduino, to reply for HTTP requests.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As it is currently written the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of inet.h class, you can simply send your data with GET or POST requests from the arduino with httpGET() and httpPOST() methods.

Check out this link, it might be useful!

http://www.open-electronics.org/the-gsmgprs-gps-shield-some-http-connections-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Just make a GET request to a PHP page on your server.

Something like http://www.yourserver.ext/sensors.php?s1=0&s2=0&s3=0
This is the simplest and most powerful way

Your PHP page will parse the Request object, store data in mySql and send back an ack to you object.
I have all this working without a problem at astrolabius.eu